# Buefy getting form values from a modal?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

Hi guys I am following documentation here: https://buefy.org/documentation/modal to learn how to build a login modal. The code below is copied from the link above.

```
<template>
    <section>
        <b-button
            label="Launch component modal"
            type="is-primary"
            size="is-medium"
            @click="isComponentModalActive = true" />

        <b-modal
            v-model="isComponentModalActive"
            has-modal-card
            trap-focus
            :destroy-on-hide="false"
            aria-role="dialog"
            aria-label="Example Modal"
            close-button-aria-label="Close"
            aria-modal>
            <template #default="props">
                <modal-form v-bind="formProps"></modal-form>
            </template>
        </b-modal>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    const ModalForm = {
        props: ['email', 'password', 'canCancel'],
        template: `
            <form action="">
                <div class="modal-card" style="width: auto">
                    <header class="modal-card-head">
                        <p class="modal-card-title">Login</p>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="delete"
                            @click="$emit('close')"/>
                    </header>
                    <section class="modal-card-body">
                        <b-field label="Email">
                            <b-input
                                type="email"
                                :value="email"
                                placeholder="Your email"
                                required>
                            </b-input>
                        </b-field>

                        <b-field label="Password">
                            <b-input
                                type="password"
                                :value="password"
                                password-reveal
                                placeholder="Your password"
                                required>
                            </b-input>
                        </b-field>

                        <b-checkbox>Remember me</b-checkbox>
                    </section>
                    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                        <b-button
                            label="Close"
                            @click="$emit('close')" />
                        <b-button
                            label="Login"
                            type="is-primary" />
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </form>
        `        
    }

    export default {
        components: {
            ModalForm
        },
        data() {
            return {
                isComponentModalActive: false,
                formProps: {
                    email: 'evan@you.com',
                    password: 'testing'
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
          login(){
            console.log("login!!!!!", this)
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This example does not explains how can we get the email and password after Login button is clicked. How should the modal pass the login input values to the login() function as shown above?

Comment: Did you checked your Vue devtools? Isn't the `email` state not updated while typing inside of it? If it's not the case, you could set a `v-model` or a `@input` on the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
    <section>
        <b-button
            label="Launch component modal"
            type="is-primary"
            size="is-medium"
            @click="isComponentModalActive = true" />

        <b-modal
            v-model="isComponentModalActive"
            has-modal-card
            trap-focus
            :destroy-on-hide="false"
            aria-role="dialog"
            aria-label="Example Modal"
            close-button-aria-label="Close"
            aria-modal>
            <template #default="props">
                <modal-form v-bind="formProps" @login="login"></modal-form>
            </template>
        </b-modal>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    const ModalForm = {
        props: ['email', 'password', 'canCancel'],
        template: `
            <form @submit="login">
                <div class="modal-card" style="width: auto">
                    <header class="modal-card-head">
                        <p class="modal-card-title">Login</p>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="delete"
                            @click="$emit('close')"/>
                    </header>
                    <section class="modal-card-body">
                        <b-field label="Email">
                            <b-input
                                type="email"
                                :value="email"
                                v-model="emailEntered"
                                placeholder="Your email"
                                required>
                            </b-input>
                        </b-field>

                        <b-field label="Password">
                            <b-input
                                type="password"
                                :value="password"
                                v-model="passwordEntered"
                                password-reveal
                                placeholder="Your password"
                                required>
                            </b-input>
                        </b-field>

                        <b-checkbox>Remember me</b-checkbox>
                    </section>
                    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                        <b-button
                            label="Close"
                            @click="$emit('close')" />
                        <b-button
                            label="Login"
                            native-type="submit"
                            type="is-primary" />
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </form>
        `,
        methods:{
            login(){
                this.$emit('login', {email:this.emailEntered, password:this.passwordEntered})
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                emailEntered: null,
                passwordEntered: null,
            }
        },
    }

    export default {
        components: {
            ModalForm
        },
        data() {
            return {
                isComponentModalActive: false,
                formProps: {
                    email: 'evan@you.com',
                    password: 'testing'
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
          login({email, password}){
            console.log("login!!!!!", email)
            console.log("login!!!!!", password)
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks to comment from Kissu, I have figured out the missing parts: setting a model, and add form submit handler to emit the model values.